# Hibernate query to get records from three related tables

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have three objects USER, CONTACT and  ACTION.

Each USER has many CONTACTS and each CONTACT has many ACTIONS

Each CONTACT and ACTION has status assigned to them, e.g. 20 or 60 or...
Please have a look at the data model.

Requirement is to get the CONTACTs having a particular status, or get the CONTACTs whose ACTIONs have that particular status.
E.g. get me CONTACTs with status 20, or CONTACTs who’s ACTIONs have status 20

At the moment I have the following query that is retrieving the CONTACTs with the status 20 and does not considers that status of the ACTIONs

USER

```
public class User {
    private Integer userID;
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName;
    private Set<Contact> contactSet = new HashSet<Contact>();
    private Set<Action> actionSet = new HashSet<Action>();
    private ContactCriteria contactCriteria;
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

CONTACT

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    private Integer contactID;
    private Integer contactStatus = 0;
    private String  givenName;
    private String  familyName;
    private String  streetAddress;
    private Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<User>();
    private Set<Action> actionSet = new HashSet<Action>();
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

ACTION

```
public class Action implements Serializable {
    private Integer actionID;
    private Integer actionStatus;
    private User    user;
    private String  actionNote;
    private Contact contact;
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Following are my mapping files:
User.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.smallworks.model" schema="smallworksdb">
 <class name="User" table="USERACCOUNT">
  <id column="USER_ID" length="500" name="userID">
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property column="USER_FIRSTNAME" generated="never" lazy="false" length="100" name="userFirstName"/>
  <property column="USER_LASTNAME" generated="never" lazy="false"  length="100" name="userLastName"/>

  <set cascade="all" fetch="select" lazy="true" name="contactSet" sort="unsorted" table="USER_CONTACT">
   <key column="USER_ID"/>
   <many-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.Contact"
     column="CONTACT_ID" order-by="CONTACT_ID" unique="false"/>
  </set>

  <!-- one to many mapping with Action -->
  <set inverse="true" lazy="true" name="actionSet" sort="unsorted" order-by="ACTION_DUE_DATE" cascade="save-update">
   <key column="USER_ID"/>
   <one-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.Action"/>
  </set>

   <!-- one to one mapping with ContactCriteria -->
   <one-to-one name="contactCriteria" class="com.smallworks.model.ContactCriteria"
            cascade="save-update" lazy="false"></one-to-one>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Contact.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.smallworks.model" schema="smallworksdb">
 <class name="Contact" table="CONTACT">
  <id column="CONTACT_ID" length="500" name="contactID">
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property column="GIVEN_NAME" generated="never" lazy="false"
   length="100" name="givenName"/>
  <property column="FAMILY_NAME" generated="never" lazy="false"
   length="100" name="familyName"/>
  <property column="STREET_ADDRESS" generated="never" lazy="false"
   length="100" name="streetAddress"/>
  <property column="CONTACT_STATUS" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="contactStatus" type="integer"/>

   <set inverse="true" lazy="false" name="userSet" sort="unsorted" table="USER_CONTACT">
    <key column="CONTACT_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.User" column="USER_ID" unique="false"/>
  </set>

  <!-- one to many mapping with Action -->
  <set inverse="true" lazy="true" name="actionSet" sort="unsorted" order-by="ACTION_DUE_DATE" cascade="save-update">
   <key column="CONTACT_ID"/>
   <one-to-many class="com.smallworks.model.Action"/>
  </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Action.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.smallworks.model" schema="smallworksdb">
 <class name="Action" table="ACTION">
  <id column="ACTION_ID" length="500" name="actionID">
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property column="ACTION_STATUS" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="actionStatus" type="integer"/>
  <!-- many to one mapping with Contact -->
  <many-to-one cascade="save-update"
   class="com.smallworks.model.Contact" column="CONTACT_ID" lazy="false"
   name="contact" not-null="true" />
  <!-- many to one mapping with User  -->
  <many-to-one class="com.smallworks.model.User" column="USER_ID"
   lazy="false" name="user" not-null="true"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My existing query is:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct c FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u INNER JOIN u.contactSet as c WHERE u.userID=:userIDPara AND c.contactStatus in (:contactStatusPara)");
    query.setParameter("userIDPara", user.getUserID());
    query.setParameterList("contactStatusPara", statusList);
    contactList = query.list();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an outer join on c.actions as a and an OR restriction on a.status.

`select distinct c FROM com.smallworks.model.User as u INNER JOIN u.contactSet as c LEFT OUTER JOIN c.actionSet a WHERE u.userID=:userIDPara AND (c.contactStatus in (:contactStatusPara) OR a.actionStatus in (: actionStatusPara)`

Comment: its complaining about "outer"  org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: OUTER near line 1, column 84 [